# How do you install the automattic developer plugin under localhost for mamp when there is an error, deprecated?

Tags: plugins, errors

The WordPress Importer plugin is throwing the following warnings:

```
Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
constructors in a future version of PHP; WP_Import has a deprecated
constructor in
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-importer/wordpress-importer.php
on line 38
```

---

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
(output started at
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-importer/wordpress-importer.php:38)
in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on
line 1228
```

Comment: Are you using PHP 7 ?

Comment: Using 5.5~5.6 for my vps, and local environment also matching, at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using PHP 5.5+ versions, the old PHP 4 things will throw errors … of course. The error comes from – as you can read – the WordPress importer plugin, which is some kind of badly treated step child of WordPress.

```
plugins/wordpress-importer/wordpress-importer.php:38
```

One solution is to use [our fork with fixes from wecodemore/GitHub](https://github.com/wecodemore/wp-importer), where you can add your patches as Pull requests. You can also pull it via *Composer*.

The other solution is to try [the Humanmade rewrite](https://github.com/humanmade/WordPress-Importer) on GitHub instead, tough I have no idea how final it is. I have filed a Pull request to get [Composer support](https://github.com/humanmade/WordPress-Importer/issues/20), but I guess it is unmaintained currently.